# Python for loop: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to implement the Newton-Raphson algorithm for some finance-based calculations.

I tried it in Python with a simple for loop, but I get this `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero` encountered in double_scalars and I also get no result of the approximation. I tried to fix it by checking every division on my own, but I found no step where Python should be forced to divide by a zero.

```py
import numpy as np
import math as m
import scipy.stats as si

def totalvol_zero(M):
    v_0 = m.sqrt(2 * abs(M))
    return v_0

def C_prime(M,v):
    C_prime = si.norm.cdf(M/v + v/2) - m.exp(-M)*si.norm.cdf(M/v - v/2)
    return C_prime


def NR(M,C_prime_obs):
    v_0 = totalvol_zero(M)
    for k in range(0,7,1):
        v_0 =  v_0 - ((C_prime(M,v_0) - C_prime_obs)/(m.sqrt(1/(m.pi * 2))*m.exp(-0.5*((M/v_0 + v_0/2)**2))))
        k += 1
    return v_0

print(NR(2,2))
```

This may be a really easy error/typo for some of you because I am still a beginner in Python but at the moment I just don't see anything wrong in this code and can't explain why this warning appeared and why I don't get any value as result.

Edit:

Sorry, I forgot about `M` and `v`. They are just explicit formulas so I didn't thought that they are the cause of this problem.

```py
def moneyness(S,K,d,r,t):
    F = S * m.exp((r-d)*t)
    M = m.log(F/K)
    return M

def totalvol(sigma,t):
    v = sigma * m.sqrt(t)
    return v
```

These are the explicit expressions for `M` and `v`. `M` defines the moneyness of an option, while `v` is the total volatility of it. But because I didn't even express M and v in the for-loop like that, but used them just as numbers for the Newton-Raphson, I don't think they will help solve the problem.

`C_prime_obs` is a converted call price of an option. The value should be always positive but since I never divided by `C_prime_obs`, this doesn't change anything.

Comment: `NameError: name 'm' is not defined`. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: The content of some of your variables are unclear (your imports are missing). WIth example input data and desired output data it's much easier to find the error.

Comment: What do you think `k += 1` is doing?

Comment: @shrewmouse `k +=1` should just make sure that the iteration is performed 6 times and I thought that I can implement it in Python like this.

Comment: @Tomerikoo sorry misunderstood it...

Comment: `for k in range(0,7,1):` will loop 7 times, with k taking values from 0 to 6. `k += 1` is useless, as `k` will take the next value of the range at the start of the next loop anyway (`k`'s value never gets tested at the start of the loop)

Comment: If you print the values of the divisor in the line causing the error, you'll see that it gets very small very quickly. The first 3 values are 0.05399096651318806, 2.6245676838606886e-28, 0.0 (this one due to rounding, as it is too small to be represented as a float)

Comment: Yes, you're right. The algorithm without the `k += 1` works. The problem with division by zero comes only by typing in values that are out of range for that calculation. I just tried to figure out a mistake in the code instead of just thinking about value ranges that still make sense. Thanks for your help.